# UIView bounds.applying but with rotation

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, cashapelayer, cgrect

I'd like to create a dash border around a view, which can be moved/rotated/scaled.

Here's my code:

```
func addBorder() {        
    let f = selectedObject.bounds.applying(selectedObject.transform)
    borderView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5) //just for testing
    borderView.frame = f
    borderView.center = selectedObject.center
    borderView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: selectedObject.transform.tx, y: selectedObject.transform.ty)

    removeBorder() //remove old border

    let f2 = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: borderView.frame.width, height: borderView.frame.height)
    let dashedBorder = CAShapeLayer()
    dashedBorder.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    dashedBorder.lineDashPattern = [2, 2]
    dashedBorder.frame = f2
    dashedBorder.fillColor = nil
    dashedBorder.path = UIBezierPath(rect: f2).cgPath
    dashedBorder.name = "border"
    borderView.layer.addSublayer(dashedBorder)
}
```

And it looks like this:
[image]

It's not bad, but I want the border to be rotated as well, because it may be misleading for the user as touch area is only on the image.

I've tried to apply rotation to the transform:

```
func addBorder() {        
    let f = selectedObject.bounds.applying(selectedObject.transform)
    borderView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5) //just for testing
    borderView.frame = f
    borderView.center = selectedObject.center
    let rotation = atan2(selectedObject.transform.b, selectedObject.transform.a)

    borderView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: rotation).translatedBy(x: selectedObject.transform.tx, y: selectedObject.transform.ty)

    removeBorder() //remove old border

    let f2 = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: borderView.frame.width, height: borderView.frame.height)
    let dashedBorder = CAShapeLayer()
    dashedBorder.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    dashedBorder.lineDashPattern = [2, 2]
    dashedBorder.frame = f2
    dashedBorder.fillColor = nil
    dashedBorder.path = UIBezierPath(rect: f2).cgPath
    dashedBorder.name = "border"
    borderView.layer.addSublayer(dashedBorder)
}
```

But after rotating it looks like this:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I've accepted the answer, because it helped me understand the issue I'm posting the final answer, because it's more to it. And I think it can be helpful for someone else, because I couldn't find this solution on Stackoverflow or somewhere else.

The idea is to create a `borderView` with bounds same as `selectedObject`. This was the solution from @Incredible_dev, however there was one issue: the line itself stretches as the `borderView` is scaled in any direction. And I want to keep the line size and just it want to be around `selectedObject`. So, I multiply `selectedObject` bounds with scale extracted from `selectedObject.transform`. Then I copy translation and rotation from the `selectedObject`.

Here's the final code:

```
var borderView: UIView!
var selectedObject: UIView?

extension CGAffineTransform { //helper extension

    func getScale() -> CGFloat {
        return (self.a * self.a + self.c * self.c).squareRoot()
    }

    func getRotation() -> CGFloat {
        return atan2(self.b, self.a)
    }

}

func removeBorder() { //remove the older border
    if borderView != nil {
        borderView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}

func addBorder() {
    guard let selectedObject = selectedObject else { return }

    removeBorder() //remove old border

    let t = selectedObject.transform
    let s = t.getScale()
    let r = t.getRotation()

    borderView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: selectedObject.bounds.width * s, height: selectedObject.bounds.height * s)) //multiply bounds with selectedObject's scale
    dividerImageView.addSubview(borderView) //add borderView to the "scene"

    borderView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: t.tx, y: t.ty).rotated(by: r) //copy translation and rotation, order is important
    borderView.center = selectedObject.center

    let dashedBorder = CAShapeLayer() //create 2-point wide dashed line
    dashedBorder.lineWidth = 2
    dashedBorder.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    dashedBorder.lineDashPattern = [2, 2]
    dashedBorder.fillColor = nil
    dashedBorder.path = UIBezierPath(rect: borderView.bounds).cgPath
    borderView.layer.addSublayer(dashedBorder)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample based on your code that should do:

```
//initial transforms
selectedObject.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle: .pi / 4).translatedBy(x: 150, y: 15)

func addBorder() {
    let borderView = UIView.init(frame: selectedObject.bounds)
    self.view.addSubview(borderView)
    borderView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5) //just for testing
    borderView.center = selectedObject.center
    borderView.transform = selectedObject.transform

    removeBorder() //remove old border

    let dashedBorder = CAShapeLayer()
    dashedBorder.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    dashedBorder.lineDashPattern = [2, 2]
    dashedBorder.fillColor = nil
    dashedBorder.path = UIBezierPath(rect: borderView.bounds).cgPath
    dashedBorder.name = "border"
    borderView.layer.addSublayer(dashedBorder)
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. It looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/OSIAaWw in my app you can scale as well. I don't want to stretch border, I just want to resize it and rotate to the right place.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution of for problem:

```
func addBorder() {

    borderView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5) //just for testing
    let degrees: CGFloat = 20.0 //the value in degrees for rotation
    let radians: CGFloat = degrees * (.pi / 180)
    borderView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: radians)

    removeBorder()

    let dashedBorder = CAShapeLayer()
    dashedBorder.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    dashedBorder.lineDashPattern = [2, 2]
    dashedBorder.frame = borderView.bounds
    dashedBorder.fillColor = nil
    dashedBorder.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: borderView.bounds, cornerRadius:0).cgPath
    dashedBorder.name = "border"
    borderView.layer.addSublayer(dashedBorder)
}
```

The above code is tested in Xcode 10 with Swift 4.2

Comment: But it just uses rotation alone. Try applying scale or translation. And even if you scale it'll stretch the CAShapeLayer path. The idea is to calculate the final border, which will have a default scale and is only rotated.

Comment: Okay, my apologies. I've made a serious tests and got it worked. In my case, I was just updating the same borderView, not creating a new one each time. It somehow messes up the frame after second transform change. But when I'm creating this again each time it works. Now, the only issue is the visual size of the border. Because my "selectObject" stats with just 0.25 scale border is already very thin and almost invisible.

Comment: I've finally did it. This finishes the trick: dashedBorder.lineWidth = CGFloat(abs(1 / scale(from: t))) where t is transform and scale method is scale extraction from transform.

Comment: Good to know. All the best.

Comment: Your answer helped me, however final code is a little more complex so I've posted it anyway. lineWidth solution wasn't perfect.